# How to read multiple command line parameters with same flag in Python?

Tags: python, parsing, command-line-arguments, getopt, python-2.4

A user should be able to call the Python script like this:

```
python myScript.py -i inputFile.txt -k string1 -k string2 -k string3 -o outputFile.txt
```

or like this:

```
python myScript.py -i inputFile.txt -o outputFile.txt -k string1 -k string2
```

Inside the script, I want to end up reading in the "-i" parameter, the "-o" parameter, and put all the "-k" parameters (variable amount) into an ordered list.

I want to do this in a clean way (I know I can write this myself from scratch, but I would rather use an already-built library/module).

I must use Python 2.4.3 and would like to use getopt (if not something similar). I am not allowed to download argparse either.

Comment: Python 2.4.3!  That's quite a requirement . . . While `argparse` was added in python2.7, it does work with previous versions (although I have no idea how far back -- 2.4 might be a bit too primitive, but you can always at least give it a shot. . .)

Comment: `argparse` is new in 2.7, but `optparse` goes all the way back to 2.3, and it's a lot closer to `argparse` than to `getopt`. The only reason to use `getopt` is if you already know `getopt` really well and have no reason to learn something that's newer (but already obsolete) like `optparse`.

Comment: @mgilson is right (as usual). [`argparse`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/argparse) on PyPI works on 2.3+.

Comment: Meanwhile, whatever library you choose, what is your actual question? If you're looking for a library recommendation, that's not a good fit for SO. If you're looking for a tutorial, the official tutorial is going to be better than anything anyone slaps together in an SO question. Pick a module (I'd suggest `argparse`, but of course that's not a recommendation :), try it, and see if you get stuck.

Comment: @abarnert -- Thank you for the compliment, and for coming up with a much better link than I found :-)

Comment: @mgilson: You don't immediately google `pypi argparse` to look up a module on PyPI? (It's a lot better than the PyPI search when looking for a specific module…)

Comment: Updated with another requirement. I cannot simply type "import argparse" in the Python script.

Comment: Why can't you import it? (And as for not being allowed to install it… even if you don't have privileges to install system packages and user site-config hasn't been set up, `argparse.py` is a single-file pure-Python module; you can just copy that file into your project directory if worst comes to worst.)

Comment: @abarnert -- No -- Usually if I need something I immediately `sudo pip install ...` without bothering to look it up on pypi ;-).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the constraints in my question (Python 2.4.3, no installation of argparse), I made it work as follows:

```
from optparse import OptionParser

parser = OptionParser()
parser.add_option('-f', action='append')
parser.add_option('-i', action='store')
parser.add_option('-o', action='store')
(options, args) = parser.parse_args()
print options
print args
```

Given this command line:

```
python test_argparse.py -f hi -f bye -i input1 -i input2 -o output1 -o output2
```

I got:

```
{'i': 'input2', 'o': 'output2', 'f': ['hi', 'bye']}
[]
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you can install `argparse`, the only tricky requirement that you have is being able to specify an argument multiple times.  `argparse` handles this flawlessly with it's `"append"` action:

```
>>> parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
>>> parser.add_argument('-k', action='append')
_AppendAction(option_strings=['-k'], dest='k', nargs=None, const=None, default=None, type=None, choices=None, help=None, metavar=None)
>>> parser.parse_args(['-k', 'foo', '-k', 'bar'])
Namespace(k=['foo', 'bar'])
```

Comment: Installing argparse is not a viable option. I am looking into optparse to see if it has such an action.